# PlayN how to add random delay to image loading in pure Java version?

Tags: playn

Any flag / config to add random delay to image loading on the Java version?
Just want to mimic the HTML behavior ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the forthcoming 1.1 release of PlayN (out by Feb 13 2012), you will be able to delay image loading slightly by passing:

```
-Dplayn.java.asyncLoad
```

on the command line. For example:

```
mvn -Dplayn.java.asyncLoad test -P test-java
```